# How to make a m.mysite.com mobile site in PHP?

Tags: php, mobile, dns, subdomain

I am following [the link](http://azure.microsoft.com/blog/2014/04/23/azure-websites-and-wildcard-domains/) to make wildcard domains. Now m.mysite.com would redirect to mysite.com. But I want it to show a different versions of the site. So that m.mysite.com would be different from mysite.com.  My mobile version is put in the htdocs/mobile folder.

So I tried

```
if  (array_shift((explode(".",$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']))) == 'm'){
    include("mobile".$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); 
    die();
}
```

The problem is, I cannot include the Get variables in the include. So if the url is m.mysite.com/read.php?id=1, the part id=1 would be missing.

How should I do it properly?

Note: This question is not about how to redirect different users to different sites according to their devices. But this is about how to set up two sites which shows different versions with a different subdomain.

Answer (score 0):

One way can do this is to download a class that detects what type of device the site is running on (ie. PC, tablet, phone) then load the CSS file appropriately. I have used this class a few times and it seems to work fine.

https://code.google.com/p/php-mobile-detect/

From here you can build up the classes and modify it in whatever way you please.

Comment: Thanks. But I don't just want to modify the css. The html also needs to be changed.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution :**

Put two folders in same root directory. First folder is mapped with mysite.com that contain different content and Second one with m.mysite.com with different content.
By doing this you can easily access both domains with different content on same web server.

Comment: Thanks. But the same problem exists... I cannot include the get variables while including files in the correct folder.

Comment: @user2335065 use wurfl, it is using for getting device information. By using this you can easily differenciate in mobile devices and show content accordingly.

Comment: But the problem is even if I can differentiate between mobile devices, I don't know how to show them the correct content accordingly.

Comment: U can easily do it by differenciate using Operating system. Wurfl provide you operating system, model, model name,etc. on that basis you can show content.

Answer (score 0):

There Is Two Way To Do This Work Simply....

First You Can Detect A Mobile And Redirect Them To A Extra Folder Using This Code

```
<?php
$agent = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']; // Put browser name into local variable

if (preg_match("/iPhone/", $agent) OR preg_match("/android/", $agent)) { //Detect Mobile Device(You Can Add More Mobile User Agent)
// Send Mobile User To Their Site
header("location: mobile.php"); //ypu can also reirect to a folder or subdomain
} 
?>
```

There Is The Second A Way...You Have To Place This Code In Your Index...

```
<?php
$agent = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']; // Put browser name into local variable
if (preg_match("/iPhone/", $agent) OR preg_match("/android/", $agent)) { //Detect Mobile   Device(You Can Add More Mobile User Agent)
include'mobile.php'; // mobile version
} 
else{
include'pc.php'; // dekstop version
}
?>
```